# JSON API Call failing from Java (but working fine in Web Browser)

Tags: java, json

I am trying to make a JSON API call to get some information exposed by another web site. The web server admins have given me the API which looks like http://www.mywebsite.com/community/explore.json

I am writing my Java program modelled on the sample code given in the below link. 
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restfull-java-client-with-java-net-url/
No compile time errors, but when I run the program I get the below error.

```
AllGroupsReader:http://www.mywebsite.com/community/explore.json
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 404
    at AllGroupsReader.getGroups(AllGroupsReader.java:43)
    at AllGroupsReader.main(AllGroupsReader.java:75)
```

The URL works perfectly fine when opened using a Web Browser. It dumps all data onto the screen. Then I also tried to just open the web site (i.e http://www.mywebsite.com) through the Java program. Even then I get a 404 error. What am I doing wrong here?

**Added later.**
Below is the code snippet I used to establish the connection. I used inputs from a sample program (link already given) to make the call. My next plan is to write a more simpler program to display the contents of say www.google.com web page. The code I use to make the API Call

```
//make the URL connection and call
HttpURLConnection urlConnection =  (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
os.flush();
if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
    + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
}
```

**The version details of my JDK**

java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

PS: I do have F-Secure anti virus software installed on my system. Don't know if it is blocking any traffic. I even disabled the Windows Firewall but it does not seem to work.

Comment: HTTP 404 means resource not found. Restful client successfully connected to server hence firewall/antivirus is not a problem. Probably your URL/ response handling in wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I have shared the code snippet used to make the API call. Will that be of help?

Answer (score 0):

I think Your problem lies with:

```
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
os.flush();
```

remove those lines and the request should work.
the problem is that you tell your connection that you want to send data to the server, which is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested below code and it's returning response. Note the tweaks I have made in your code. I am just sharing the working example and have not optimized it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    try {

        URL url = new URL("http://www.mywebsite.com/community/explore.json");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection =  (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line = null;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + urlConnection.getResponseCode());

        }
        System.out.println(sb);
    }

    finally{

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is resolved. I had to re-work on the code. Basically the issue was that I was confused between the GET and POST features when using HttpURLConnection. Now I am able to retrieve the data and also convert it into JSON object.

```
//compose the URL
String exploreJSONCall = JSON_API_LIST.EXPLORE_API;
log(exploreJSONCall);
URL myURL = new URL(exploreJSONCall);
HttpURLConnection yc = (HttpURLConnection) myURL.openConnection();
yc.setRequestMethod("GET");
yc.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
log("Content type expected:"+yc.getContentType());

//a basic check on response code. 
int respCode = yc.getResponseCode();
log("Response code received:"+Integer.toString(respCode));
if (respCode != 200) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "+respCode);
}
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        yc.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
    log(inputLine);
```